# Could not connect pins - RenderStream(): Unity3d WebCamTexture error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webcam

Simple code snippet to get WebCam input into unity3d.

```
        string deviceName = devices[index].name;
        objWebCam = new WebCamTexture(deviceName);//, 400, 300, 12 //overloads
        gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.mainTexture = objWebCam;
        objWebCam.Play();
```

And I am frequently getting this error

```
Could not connect pins - RenderStream()
UnityEngine.WebCamTexture:Play
```

But (**for solution**) when I

1. Restart my unity application (OR)
2. Re-plug my WebCam (OR)
3. Restart my PC

Then, it didn't show any error and works correctly. Why I am getting this error frequently?

Answer (score 0):

The error message mentioning "RenderStream" supposedly corresponds to problem that Unity3D is unable to build a video streaming pipeline using DirectShow API. The message itself is not showing the root cause and in the order of probability (most probable first) it can be:

- your code attempts to use one camera in 2+ places simultaneously, whereas the camera is exclusive use resource
- WebCamTexture implementation and webcam driver have certain incompatibility which results in inability to construct new streaming sessions
- problem in webcam driver that somehow fails to close video capture session so that next attempt to use WebCamTexture fails; restart of the application (closed hosting process) cleans the problem up