# Unity error: Could not connect pins - RenderStream() -- only on my Logitech cameras

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webcam

I am encountering this error when attempting to play a stream from my Logitech cameras but not from cameras of different make.

`Could not connect pins - RenderStream()`

This is essentially my code:

```
webCamTexture = new WebCamTexture(WebCamTexture.devices[0].name, 1280, 720, 30);
rawImage.texture = webCamTexture;
webCamTexture.Play();
```

- Windows standalone app
- Unity 2023.3.1f1
- Windows 11

It's happening on my two different models of Logitech cameras, c270 and c922, but working fine with two same model ELP cameras.

It doesn't seem to be a problem with the cameras or their drivers as I have written a Windows WPF C# program using AForge which streams all the cameras correctly (except the fact that it won't work with two same-model logitech cameras on the same usb hub).

Does anyone have a proven and workable solution for this?

**Similar postings I've found...**

- 6days ago https://discussions.unity.com/t/could-not-connect-pins-renderstream-unityengine-stacktraceutility-extractstacktrace/262224
- 2023 https://forum.unity.com/threads/could-not-connect-pins-renderstream-unityengine-stacktraceutility-extractstacktrace.1451434/
- 2016 [Could not connect pins - RenderStream(): Unity3d WebCamTexture error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38758702/could-not-connect-pins-renderstream-unity3d-webcamtexture-error)
- 2015 https://forum.unity.com/threads/could-not-connect-pins-renderstream.356953/
- 2011 https://forum.unity.com/threads/webcamtexture-play-error-on-win8-tablet-log-could-not-connect-pins-renderstream.160203/